# Angular 5 weird behavior on https calls

Tags: node.js, angular, httpclient, interceptor

We are using angular 5 and nodejs for our application and we are facing a weird behavior in our production.We are sending a request call using httpclient from angular and when it gets a delayed response, it starts to retry the request in every 2 minutes as a default behavior.Once the request gets the response,it stops retrying the request.We are having a subscribe method inside another subscribe.

```
  this._inspectionPageService.transferCheck(this.org)
  .subscribe(status => {
    if (status === true){
    this._inspectionPageService.saveReceipts(this.genId, this.receiptData)
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.receiptInfo = results;
      });
    } else {
      this._sharedServices.throwMessage('error', 'Failed.Please try Again');
    }
  });
```

Here saveReceipts call is taking more than 2 minutes to complete the request.

We are not using any retry method.Our interceptors also do not have any retry methods.This occurs strangely.

When we checked the log,we found the multiple entries in the difference of two minutes.We tried to replicate this issue in test instance,but unable to reproduce it.

Does anybody have idea on this?

Comment: Worth trying pipe to take(1) and catchError for   this._inspectionPageService.transferCheck(this.org) .. also check this article out https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/retry-failed-http-requests-in-angular-f5959d486294

Comment: Try using a switchMap, as it will cancel all older subscriptions.

Comment: Could you please tell us why this strange behavior occurs only in production?Why it could not be reproduced in test instance?Is that because of the timeout or any default interval for timeout has been predetermined in angular httpclient?